# Importing multiple slightly different excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to import tables from multiple excel files to a python, specifically with a Panda Dataframe format.
The problem is that the excel files do not have all the same structure,
particularly in some of them the table starts at the cell A1 while in another start at cell A2 or even B1 or B2. 
The only thing that stays constant through all excel files are  the headers positioned in the first row of the table.

So for instance in the first row in the very right of the table is always written "setting". But "setting" is sometimes written at position A1 and sometimes at position B2.

Currently, I am just modifying manually numHeader and skip parameters in the pandas.read_excel method for each single excel, but since there is quite a lot of file doing this manually every time is quite a waste of time.

```
CurrExcelFile = pd.read_excel(Files[i], \
                                   header=numHeader, skiprows=skip)
```

Is there exist, or can it be easily written a package which takes as a parameter a string for identifying the first element of a table?

So that I could just pass "setting" and the script could get automatically the index of the cell and start fetching data from there.

UPDATE:
So currently I managed to it by first importing the whole sheet, find where it is the "setting" value, then dropping the unnecessary columns, rename the data frame and finally dropping the unnecessary rows.

```
Test = pd.read_excel('excelfile',sheet_name='sheetname')

#Find the index and the column of the first cell
for column in Test.columns:
    tmp = Test[column] == "setting"
    if len(Test.loc[tmp].index) == 1:
        RowInd = Test.loc[tmp].index[0]
        ColPos = Test.columns.get_loc(column)

#Drop Columns
ColumnsToDrop = Test.columns[np.arange(0,ColPos)]
Test.drop(ColumnsToDrop, inplace=True, axis=1)

#Rename Axis
Test.columns =  (Test.iloc[RowInd])

#Drop Rows
Test.drop(np.arange(0,RowInd+1), inplace=True, axis=0)
```

This is rather a workaround and I wish there was a easier solution

Comment: Can you give us some example code?

Comment: pd.read_excel file is what I am changing manually now